# Authors on the same line, change after authblk is loaded

Tags: titles, authblk

Without loading the authblk package, if a document has 2 authors they are put next to each other (unless wide) on a titlepage. After loading the authblk package, the 2 authors are above each other. Is there a way to retain the next-to-each-other arrangement even with the authblk package loaded.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{authblk}
\title{title}%
\date{\today}%
\author{%
author 1 \\ author 1 university%
\and
author 2 \\ author 2 university}%
\date{ ~ \\ \today }%
\begin{document}
\maketitle%
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`authblk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) documentation, you have to use the `\author{...}\affil{...}` notation, and set the `noblocks` package option. This will give you the footnote style of affiliation notation, which isn't quite the same as the original, but the only way I can see to keep them on one line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\title{title}%
\date{\today}%
\author{%
author 1}
\affil{author 1 university}%
\author{author 2}
\affil{author 2 university}%
\date{ ~ \\ \today }%
\begin{document}
\maketitle%
\end{document}
```

[image: authblk]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do this,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{, \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother

\title{Your Title}
\author[1]{author1}
\author[2]{author2}

\affil[1]{author 1 university}
\affil[2]{author 1 university}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The output is,

[image]